# Are there any known bounds on the value of solutions of linear integer programming?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mathematical-modeling, combinatorial-optimization

Given a linear objective function and a system of linear constraints; are there any known bounds on the values of (positive) integral solutions in terms of the coefficient matrix of the constraints?

More specifically, the objective function (to be minimized) is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$ and the coefficients of the constraints are restricted to the set $\{\pm1, \pm2\}$.

Comment: The objective function could be unbounded...

Comment: @IgorRivin: Minimizing the sum of positive integers?

Comment: I did not notice the "minimize" part.

Comment: By "coefficients of the constraints", do you also mean the constant part of the constraint?

Comment: @J.FabianMeier Assuming no constant terms.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "positive integral solution"? All variables to be strictly greater than zero?